# How to call a tiny house made of cardboard by a person who would otherwise be homeless?

Tags: word-request

Some homeless people gather cardboard boxes to build a tiny volume where they can sleep with less wind than if just outside.

How to call such a "home"?

- I see "homeless house" being used but it sounds a bit paradoxical.
- A Google Images search for "street dwelling" shows images of small but brick-and-mortar houses, so I guess it is not the word I am looking for either.

I am writing a reference text, so I would prefer a term used by government agencies or NGOs, rather than slang.

[image: Homeless in Tokyo]

Comment: "cardboard box house"?

Comment: I might call it a "makeshift cardboard shelter". I don't know if there is a single word that means this.

Comment: @InitK: Sounds good, would you mind making an answer? maybe with a reference? :-)

Comment: A very minor correction: "cardboard" is a noncount noun, like most materials, so it would be "made of cardboard", not "made of cardboards".

Comment: You can just say *cardboard house*, like you can *brick house* or *wood house*

Comment: As in [A homeless women and her belongings lives in **a cardboard house** on a street near the Pompidou Centre Paris France Europe](http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-a-homeless-women-and-her-belongings-lives-in-a-cardboard-house-on-7709953.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are many way it can be called. Just from one article - two different ways - *cardboard-dwelling* and *cardboard-box home*:

http://www.app.com/story/news/local/monmouth-county/2015/09/29/homeless-night-lessons-cardboard-box-city/72727172/

But, it can be called just a ...*cardboard box*.

Edit: not really a great reference, but there you go: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CardboardBoxHome

Comment: Indeed! I found this song: **[Living in a cardboard box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_in_a_Box_(song))**

Comment: Or just *cardboard house*.

Comment: In the US "cardboard box" is the most common way to refer to it. For example, "If I lose this job I'm going to end up sleeping in a cardboard box." It doesn't matter if some of the structures are more than one box if you are referring to them in general. We might be more descriptive if we're talking about a specific structure or camp. @CopperKettle

Comment: @CopperKettle: Luxury! When I were a lad, [*we lived for three months in a **brown paper bag** in a septic tank*](http://www.davidpbrown.co.uk/jokes/monty-python-four-yorkshiremen.html), before the council upgraded us to a small shoebox in the middle of the road. (But we were 'appy! :)